# Почему я могу не ловить событие?

Tags: c#, reactive

У меня есть класс с конструктором, в котором я вызываю нужные методы с ивентами. Проблема в том, что события то ловятся, то нет. Не особо понятно, что на это влияет, они должны нормально работать

```
public class MainWindowViewModel : ReactiveObject                   
{                                                                                                                                    
    public MainWindowViewModel()                                 
    {                                                                                                                               
        ReactiveCommand.CreateFromTask( async () =>                 
        {                                                           
            await NCInitialize();                                   
            await ControllerInitialize();                           
            await AccessPointInitialize();                          
        } ).Execute(); 
   }

private async Task NCInitialize()                                       
{                                                                       
    var ncPortClient = await _serviceProvider.GetNCPortClientFactory()   
        .Create( _signature, _context.RemoteNodeName );                  
                                                                        
    await ncPortClient.EventReceived                                     
        .AddHandler( async ( context, @event ) =>   {}                                                              
}
```

Ожидаю, что я попаду в ncPortClient.EventReceived, но частенько это не происходит. Могут ли таски, которые ожидаю, как-то повлиять на все это?

Реактивный команды - это [reactive ui](https://www.reactiveui.net/)

Comment: это что? Rx.NET?

Comment: @aepot https://www.reactiveui.net/

Comment: Об этом надо явно указывать в посте.

Comment: @aepot почитал щас документацию, в которой советуется после Execute, использовать Subscribe. Комментарий, который там был: // observable returned by Execute is cold, so we need to Subscribe to let it execute. У меня вопрос: а что такое cold?

Comment: Создан, но не запущен.

Comment: странно тогда,  что созданная таска могла работать ( хоть и с багами )